# How to print Nag symbols ⩱ ⩲ ⟳ ?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to print nag symbols on UILabel.

⩱  ⩲ ⟳

these three symbols are not printing correctly on UILabel.

i also tried :-
    UniChar str = 0x27F3;
        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&str length:1];

```
    [lblNextMove setText:myString];
```

I got the symbols from this link:-[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_Annotation_Glyphs)

While most symbols are printing correctly i am not able to print these three.

I want to know why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't generating your strings properly.

For example, to get the slight advantage symbol as listed on that page you can generate a string:

```
NSString *slightAdvantageString = @"\u2213";
```

Which shows in a label as:

[image]

Comment: As i mentioned only specific symbols are giving problem can you replicate the result for 2a72